# Python: Tie an action to a Checkbutton

Tags: python, tkinter

From what I've been able to find in internet tutorials, the Checkbutton has a *`command`* option.  So, either this is incorrect, or I am stumped as to how to use the option.  What I'm trying to do is to have a text Entry box be gray (`disabled`) when the Checkbutton is not checked, and to enable the text Entry box when the Checkbutton is checked.

My code:
    class OutputSettings:
      def **init**(self, master):

```
    frame = LabelFrame(master, text = 'Debug')
    frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan = 2)

    self.make_txt = BooleanVar()
    self.make_txt.set(True)

    self.create_a_file = Checkbutton(frame, text = 'Create Text File')
    self.create_a_file.config(variable = self.make_txt, 
                              command = self.graytextbox())
    self.create_a_file.pack()


    Label(frame, 
          text="Text File \nSave Location:", 
          font = "Verdana 8").pack()

    self.file_location = StringVar()
    self.file_location =   Entry (frame, width=30, textvariable = self.file_location)
    self.file_location.pack()
    self.file_location.insert(0, 'C:\Temp\ETHresults.txt')


  def graytextbox(self):

    if self.make_txt == True:
        self.file_location.config(state=DISABLED)
        # I've also tried self.file_location.state(['DISABLED'])
    else:
        self.file_location.config(state=NORMAL)
        # I've also tried self.file_location.state(['NORMAL'])
```

Not only does the code not control the normal/disabled function of the button, but I get `AttributeError: instance has no attribute 'file_location'`

Comment: I assume you are talking about TKinter?

Comment: remove the parenthesis `()` from the line where you are configuring the check button.  you want to give tkinter a reference to the function, not call the function and give tkinter the result.